# General solution of high order DE with repeated and complex roots

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, homogeneous-equation

I have the following question. Find the general solution of:

$$y^{(5)} - 2y^{(4)} + 3y^{(3)} = 0$$

I found the characteristic equation

$$r^3(r^2 - 2r + 3) = 0$$

With roots: $$r = 0, \ \ multiplicity:3 \\and \ \ \ r = 1\pm\sqrt2i$$

The general solution I found is:
$$y = C_1e^{(0)t}+C_2te^{(0)t}+C_3t^2e^{(0)t}+C_4e^tcos(\sqrt2t)+C_5e^tsin(\sqrt2t)$$

Simplifying to:
$$y = C_1+C_2t+C_3t^2+C_4e^tcos(\sqrt2t)+C_5e^tsin(\sqrt2t)$$

Is this the correct solution?  I am unsure whether or not root multiplicity applies to an $\mathbf{r^3 = 0}$ root.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: My mistake.  I meant to write $1\pm\sqrt2i$

Comment: If you call $u=y'''$ then the ODE is $u''-2u+3u=0.$ Then $y''=\int u +c_3,$ $y'=\int u+c_3t+c_2$ and $y=\int u+c_3t^2+c_2t+c_1.$ So your solution is correct. Anyway, you don't need to introduce $e^0$ in the general solutions. Is not $c_1+c_2t+c_3t^2$ the general solution of $y'''=0?$

Comment: I'm still confused.  Why do I not need to introduce $e^0$?  Is the final solution I have correct?

Comment: Your solution is correct. But I don't understand the reason to write $e^0.$ Is not $e^0=1?$

Comment: I just wrote it that way for clarity sake.  Thanks for the help!